# Python circular import, can't import a function between two files?

Tags: python, fastapi

I'm facing an annoying problem with a circular import error and I don't understand what I am doing wrong. Here the code:

main.py

```
import uvicorn
import app.config.config as config

app = config.load_config()
CONFIG = config.read_config()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host=CONFIG["APPLICATION"]["HOST"], port=CONFIG["APPLICATION"]["PORT"])
```

config.py

```
import os
import toml
import logging
import app.api.routing as routing
from fastapi import FastAPI

BASE_DIR = os.getcwd()


def read_config():
    try:
        CONFIG = toml.load(BASE_DIR + "/config.toml")
        return CONFIG
    except FileNotFoundError as err:
        logging.error(f"Unable to read configuration file: {err}")
        return None


def load_config():
    app = FastAPI()
    app.include_router(routing.router)
    return app
```

database.py

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, sessionmaker
import app.config.config as config

CONFIG = config.read_config()

USERNAME = CONFIG["POSTGRES"]["USERNAME"]
PASSWORD = CONFIG["POSTGRES"]["PASSWORD"]
HOSTNAME = CONFIG["POSTGRES"]["HOSTNAME"]
DATABASE = CONFIG["POSTGRES"]["DATABASE"]
PORT = CONFIG["POSTGRES"]["PORT"]

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = f"postgresql://{USERNAME}:{PASSWORD}@{HOSTNAME}:{PORT}/{DATABASE}"
engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)
Base = declarative_base()


def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()
```

ERROR:

```
CONFIG = config.read_config()
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'app.config.config' has no attribute 'read_config' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

I'm using FastAPI framework with Python 3.9.
In the code, I have imported "app.config.config" 2 times (main.py and database.py) and I need to import this config file to use the function `read_config()` contained in it.

Anyone can help please? Thanks

THE PROJECT STRUCTURE:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── api
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── routing.py
│   ├── config
│   │   ├── config.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── settings.py
│   ├── database
│   │   ├── database.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── main.py
│   ├── models
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └──  placesModel.py
│   └── service
│       ├── crud.py
│       ├── __init__.py
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could it be that your import needs to be `app.config`, not `app.config.config`?

Comment: Nope, I have the folder ```config ``` and inside it, I have another file called ```config.py```. So ```app.config.config``` I think it's correct... :(

Comment: Can you give us the architecture of your project?

Comment: This is a guess because you haven't provided all the code, nor the full stack trace. But `config` is doing `import app.api.routing` and I suspect that module is importing `app.config.config`.

Comment: Yes, I just added it

Comment: try to change the name of your 'config' folder (same with the file), it is possible that one of the modules you import uses an identical path, so, when importing this module, it confuses with another, and cause thus a circular import without your knowledge

Comment: I just tried, but it doesnt work

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that `app.api.routing` try to import `database`.

- First try to refactor your code and split `routing` so it doesn't require `database`
- Otherwise, make call to `read_config` in `database` just-in-time. There are various solutions to differ call to `read_config`.

```py
def _get_session_local():
    NFIG = config.read_config()
    ...
    return sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)


def get_db():
    if get_db._get_session_local is None:
        get_db._session_local = _get_session_local()
    try:
        yield get_db._session_local()
    finally:
        db.close()
get_db._session_local = None
```

More generally, the execution of code during import is to be avoided.